# How to run Entity Framework on a background thread in SpecFlow (MS-Test)

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, mstest, specflow

I am running integration-tests in SpecFlow.

The Tests involve accessing a database with Entity Framework 6. Data Access has to run on a background thread because the code involves thread locking logic **that I cannot change at the moment**.

It would run fine, if EF Queries are started from the test-thread directly, but unfortunately in the real scenario, I have to do it from a worker thread.

*The excample is minimized to the smallest possible sample, that reproduce the error: In reality there is more than just a EF Query, but it is the first query that throws.*

My Test code looks like this:

```cs
    [When("...")]
    public async Task When_IReadData()
    {
        var context = new MyContext();

        // This works fine, but...
        var data1 = context.Whatevers.ToList();

        // Act
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // ...in the real case I have to run it from a background thread.
            var data2 = context.Whatevers.ToList(); // This throws an exception
        });

        await task;
    }
```

Once I try to query the database from, it runs into a TimeoutException.

It makes no difference where I create the context or explicitly using a thread instead of the Task.Run.

It only happens in the When/Then Bindings... Putting the same code somewhere else (like in Test Initialize) works fine. So I guess there's some specFlow execution handling stopping the queries from finishing.

This is the exception:

```
Message: 
Test method Euv.Modules.DatenPflegen.Tests.V2.Features.StuecklistePflegen.KomponenteAusbauenFeature.VorDemAusbauenEinerKomponenteDieNichtINTIstKannAbgebrochenWerden_ threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
Stack Trace: 
SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
List`1.ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
StuecklistePflegenBinding.<When_IchBaueDieKomponenteAus>b__28_0() line 432
Task.InnerInvoke()
Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
<When_IchBaueDieKomponenteAus>d__28.MoveNext() line 431
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
<<InvokeBindingDelegateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() line 31
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
<<RunSync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
ExclusiveSynchronizationContext.BeginMessageLoop() line 115
AsyncHelpers.RunSync[T](Func`1 task) line 71
SynchronousBindingDelegateInvoker.InvokeBindingDelegateAsync(Delegate bindingDelegate, Object[] invokeArgs) line 27
SynchronousBindingDelegateInvoker.InvokeDelegateSynchronously(Delegate bindingDelegate, Object[] invokeArgs) line 16
BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration) line 49
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments) line 521
TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance) line 426
TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep() line 207
TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors() line 59
KomponenteAusbauenFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
KomponenteAusbauenFeature.VorDemAusbauenEinerKomponenteDieNichtINTIstKannAbgebrochenWerden_() line 29
```

(From the actual Test.)
My guess is that my the **ExclusiveSynchronizationContext** from SpecFlow is causing the Issue here.

The TimeOutException is probably caused by the Command Timeout of EntityFramework (30s).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by it must run in a background thread. You have a line of code `var data1 = context.Whaters.ToList();` and you say it works. Why not use that?

Comment: I clarified the example. It's just the simplest possible code to reproduce the error. The real logic is a lot more complex, but it's that line that is enough to get it to throw.

Comment: Can you add the full exception message and stack trace to your question? Maybe the TimeoutException is wrapping another exception, which is the true problem to solve.

Comment: Yes, of cause. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess (based on the stacktrace) that EF actually runs SQL command and it gets blocked. While running the test, check active processes in SQL Server Management Studio and see if any process is blocked by another process.